# CDK: Template format error: Parameter count 63 is greater than max allowed 60

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-cdk

Cloud formation seems to have a limit of 60 parameters, but these parameters are set by DEFAULT by AWS-CDK.
I'm just creating lambdas like this:

```
const adminAddUserToGroup = new lambda.Function(this, 'adminAddUserToGroup', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      handler: 'changeUserGroup.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('./lambda/AdminAddUserToGroup/'),
      functionName: 'adminAddUserToGroup'
})
```

and 3 parameters for each lambda are created (see **hash** at the picture).

Cloud formation seems to suggest using maps when the limit is reached, but this is set by CDK and **there is no documentation** how to modify these default parameters.
(please no solution like just create 2 stacks...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the last version (before some few days) CDK has fixed this long-lasting issue if you do this :

cdk.json:

```
{
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/core:newStyleStackSynthesis": true
  }
}
```

You also have to bootstrap any environments you want to deploy into using the new version of the bootstrap stack:

```
$ env CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1 npx cdk bootstrap \
  --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess \
  aws://123456789012/eu-central-1
```

*123456789012 and region should be changed based on your account*

With this solution, It won't user parameters at all.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3463 here for more